# Evitar que se agregue un número repetido en un array Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, function, javascript-metodo

Estoy intentando llenar un Select con números entre 1 y 100, además de eso evitar que se agreguen números repetidos y números negativo.

No entiendo porque me está arrojando un error al momento de la verificación.

```
let num = document.getElementById('num').value;
let lista = document.getElementById('lista');
let res = document.querySelector('div#res');
let valores = [];

function isNumero(n) {
    if (Number(n) >= 1 && Number(n) <= 100) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function inLista(n, l) {
    if (l.indexOf(Number(n)) != -1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function addNum() {
    if ((isNumero(num) && !inLista(num,valores)) {
        valores.push(Number(num));
        let item = document.createElement('option');
        item.text = `Valor ${num} agregado.`;
        lista.appendChild(item);
    } else {
        alert('Valor no agregado.');
    }
}

> Cita en bloque
```

Comment: function addNum() {..} no veo le envies ningun parametro?

Comment: @nestdan num es una variable global que definió en la linea 1

Comment: @ 

  

@Fedex7501 gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se qué error estás obteniendo exactamente pero puedes optimizar un poco tu código

```
function isNumero(n) {
    return n >= 1 && n <= 100;
}

function addNum() {
    const parsedNum = Number.parseInt(num);
    if (
        isNumero(parsedNum) &&
        !valores.includes(parsedNum)
    ){
        valores.push(parsedNum);
        let item = document.createElement('option');
        item.text = `Valor ${num} agregado.`;
        lista.appendChild(item);
    } else {
        alert('Valor no agregado.');
    }
}
```

Edit: además creo que deberías poner `let num = document.getElementById('num').value;`  dentro de la función `addNum` para que el valor se actualize

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu repuesta, ya puedo agregar el valor a la lista sin problema. En efecto, tenía que colocar ``` let num = document.getElementById('num').value; ``` dentro de la función addNum(). También tomé tu consejo de optimizar el código.

Comment: Óptimo. Te agracecería que aceptaras la respuesta como correcta entonces.